# How to pass a variable column name to the "by" command?

Tags: r, data.table

I use the data.table package in R to summarize data often.  In this particular case, I'm just counting the number of occurrences in a dataset for given column groups.  But I'm having trouble incorporating a loop to do this dynamically.

Normally, I'd summarize data like this.

```
data <- data.table(mpg)
data.temp1 <- data[, .N, by="manufacturer,class"]
data.temp2 <- data[, .N, by="manufacturer,trans"]
```

But now I want to loop through the columns of interest in my dataset and plot.  Rather than repeating the code over and over, I want to put it in a for loop.  Something like this:

```
columns <- c('class', 'trans')

for (i in 1:length(columns)) {
    data.temp <- data[, .N, by=list(manufacturer,columns[i])]
    #plot data
}
```

If I only wanted the column of interest, I could do this in the loop and it works:

```
data.temp <- data[, .N, by=get(columns[i])]
```

But if I want to put in a static column name, like manufacturer, it breaks.  I can't seem to figure out how to mix a static column name along with a dynamic one.  I've looked around but can't find an answer.

Would appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be fine if you just quote `"manufacturer"

```
data.temp <- data[, .N, by=c("manufacturer",columns[i])]
```

From the `?'[.data.table'` help page, `by=` can be

> A single unquoted column name, a list() of expressions of column names, a single character string containing comma separated column names (where spaces are significant since column names may contain spaces even at the start or end), or **a character vector of column names**.

This seems like the easiest way to give you what you need.

Comment: You're totally right!  Not sure how I missed that.. I thought for sure I tried that.  Thanks!